# Programmatic selection of list item using the new navigationDestination API

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationstack

I was wondering if anybody could help with achieving the following using the new `navigationDestination` API. Currently, I am creating a CoreData entity within a child view (`AddEventsView`) and then opening the recently created entity by passing the id from the `AddEventsView` back up to the `EventsView` using @Binding.

**EventsView**

```swift
struct EventsView: View {
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var festivals: FetchedResults<Festivals>
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    
    @State var showEditView = false
    @State var recentlyAddedFestivalId: UUID!
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                if showEditView {
                    Group {
                        Spacer().frame(height: 20)
                        AddEventsView(showEditView: $showEditView, recentlyAddedFestivalId: $recentlyAddedFestivalId)
                        Spacer().frame(height: 20)
                        Divider()
                    }
                    .padding(.leading, 20)
                    .padding(.trailing, 20)
                }
                
                // TODO: Migrate to the new navigationDestination API
                List(festivals) { festival in
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: TestView2(festivalName: festival.festival_name!, startDate: festival.start_date!, endDate: festival.end_date!),
                        tag: festival.id!,
                        selection: $recentlyAddedFestivalId
                    ){
                        VStack {
                            Text("Item: \(festival.id!)")
                            Text(festival.festival_name ?? "Unknown")
                            TestView()
                        }
                    }
                    .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                    .listRowInsets(.init(top: 20, leading: 20, bottom: 20, trailing: 20))
                }
                .listStyle(.plain)
                
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button(action: {
                        withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.25)) {
                            showEditView.toggle()
                        }
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Events")
        }
    }
}
```

---

**AddEventsView**

```swift
struct AddEventsView: View {
    @State private var festivalName: String = ""
    @State private var startDate = Date.now
    @State private var endDate = Date.now
    
    @Binding var showEditView: Bool
    @Binding var recentlyAddedFestivalId: UUID!
    
    @FocusState private var focusedField: FocusedField?
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
   
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            TextField("**Festival Name**", text: $festivalName)
                .submitLabel(.next)
                .autocorrectionDisabled()
                .font(.title3)
                .focused($focusedField, equals: .festivalName)
                .textInputAutocapitalization(.words)
            
            DatePicker(selection: $startDate, in: Date.now..., displayedComponents: .date) {
                Text("**Start Date**")
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
            }
            
            DatePicker(selection: $endDate, in: Date.now..., displayedComponents: .date) {
                Text("**End Date**")
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
            }

            Button(action: {
                let festival = Festivals(context: moc)
                festival.id = UUID()
                festival.festival_name = festivalName
                festival.start_date = startDate
                festival.end_date = endDate
                
                try? moc.save()
                
                UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
                
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.25) {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.25)) {
                        showEditView.toggle()
                        recentlyAddedFestivalId = festival.id
                        print(recentlyAddedFestivalId.debugDescription)
                    }
                }
            }) {
                Text("Done")
                    .padding(10)
                    .frame(minWidth: 300)
            }
            .foregroundStyle(.white)
            .background(.blue)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8))
            .padding(.top, 20)
            
        }
        .padding()
        .background(.regularMaterial)
        .cornerRadius(8)
        .onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.25) {
                self.focusedField = .festivalName
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is a video of the behavior im trying to achieve.

[Navigation video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPa3w.gif)

I took a look at Apple's documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-to-new-navigation-types) but failed to get it to work.

I have also looked at other questions on SO regarding migrating [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%27init(destination:tag:selection:label:)%27+was+deprecated+in+iOS+16.0:+use+NavigationLink(value:label:),+or+navigationDestination(isPresented:destination:),+inside+a+NavigationStack+or+NavigationSplitView+site:stackoverflow.com&sca_esv=557804163&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiSo73H_eOAAxXaSjABHfZRAq4QrQIoBHoECCAQBQ) but have not been able to achieve the above behavior.